# Create a datepicker in angular js

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen datepickers online but most of them seem to use JQuery. I am using bootstrap CSS for the front end but not with bootstrap.js

I dont want to use angular ui-bootstrap for this

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @LFMarabunta i dont want to use angular ui

Comment: what about https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker

Comment: So what do you want to accomplish with this question? You don't like `uib-datepicker` then find a datepicker you like and write a AngularJS directive for it.  If a jQuery plugin can do it; an AngularJS directive can do it.

Comment: @georgeawg i want an already written one im a beginner in angular js

Answer (score 0):

**(Before Question Was Changed to say no ui-bootstrap)**

## UI-Bootstrap

You should use Bootstrap.ui. it comes with a date picker and means that you don't need a jQuery dependency since its built entirely with angular. [Here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) is a link to the documentation.

Great thing about it is that it works with the bootstrap css directly so you can still use bootstrap themes.

Comment: i dont want to use ui bootstrap

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't use ui bootstrap with angular since there built with angular. You don't need the dependencies from jQuery for bootstrap and your html is just extended with new angular directives.